# Determine applied force due to torque

Tags: torque, seals

I'm hoping for some clarification regarding converting torque to force at point of contact.
I'm tightening some threaded components, the end faces of each are machined and will form a metal-metal seal under compression. I would like an idea of the force being applied at the interface due to a prescribed torque.

Using T = F.r (neglecting friction) the following values apply:
T = 5N.m (setting of torque wrench)
r = 0,0275 m (lever length of torque wrench)

I calculate F = 181,82 N but I think this force is referring to how hard my arm is pushing the wrench to achieve the desired torque.

Can anyone clarify this and suggest how I might go about finding the force at the interface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty short torque wrench you got there :P maybe a 0 too much behind the comma?

Comment: Arg! You're correct - I've mistyped! However, am I correct in thinking that I'm actually calcuating the force applied to the wrench rather than the force provided to the interface? ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the clamp force, or axial force applied by the screw threads based on your input torque (radial force x lever arm). [Here's a useful calculator](https://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/torque_calc.htm)

Comment: Thanks jko - I've used the calculator and found what seems to be reasonable answer!